# SQL Server sort VARCHAR with letters and numbers

Tags: sql-server

How do I sort a varchar value in SQL Server? The varchar can't be converted to an int, because it contains letters and numbers. This is a fairly standard query that does not work as shown:

```
select distinct Rij from [dbo].[Kist] Order by Rij desc
```

Output:

```
61
54
5
4
3
23
21
13
12
11
10D
10C
10A
1
```

I tried the follow query:

```
select
  Rij
from
  Kist
order by
  isnumeric(Rij) desc,
  case when isnumeric(Rij) = 1 then cast(Rij as int) else null end,
  Rij
```

Only problem here is that the values with numbers and letters will be last, like the value '10D' for example. Another problem here is that I can't use the DISTINCT method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
select Rij
from Kist
Order by CAST(LEFT(Rij, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Rij + 'a') - 1) as int)
```

This query works perfect, only thing is that I can't use distinct because SQL does not identify the order by clause the same as the select column. How do I do this?

EDIT:
Fixed it by using a Group by clause:

```
select Rij
from Kist
Group by Rij
Order by CAST( LEFT(Rij, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Rij + 'a') - 1) as int)
```

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in a subquery, then order. Also, don't use `ISNUMERIC`, is an awful function. Use `TRY_CONVERT`, it is far better.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for your comment. I edited the post, please check. I can't figure out how to only show unique values here.

Comment: `PATINDEX` is neither a subquery or `TRY_CONVERT`?

Comment: @Larnu, SQL is fairly new to me so please help we with this. No this is not a subquery, bit like you said to get it to show only unique values I gotta use a subquery right? But I don't know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, use `DISTINCT` in a subquery, and use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Rij
      FROM Kist) K
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,K.Rij) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         TRY_CONVERT(int,K.Rij),
         Rij;
```

Comment: Edge Item:  100A will come before 10A  and 1A will follow 10D for example